# How to prevent overstay suspicion in the UK, when entering by the UK and exiting through Ireland

Tags: eu-citizens, common-travel-area

Assume an EU/EEA/Swiss (And not Irish) citizen doing a trip consisting of the UK and Ireland with an entry in the former and the exit from the latter.

Since EU citizens aren't stamped when entering through the CTA, Ireland doesn't stamp EU citizens as does Schengen, how can you eliminate any suspicion when entering again in the CTA through the UK?

Comment: Actually, IIRC, Ireland does not stamp any passports at all on exit (like the UK and US). Don't know how the UK exit notifications work for exit via the ROI. I would guess either they record departures to the ROI (which would work for planes and ferries, but not if you cross the land border), or the ROI participates in the same system. Or it's just a big hole and plenty of people fall into it every single day :-)

Comment: https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/695321/An_inspection_of_exit_checks.pdf says "In March 2016, the Irish Government created the legal basis for the Irish-based carriers to provide API on CTA passengers to the UK authorities (...) Despite this, inspectors discovered that, almost 18 months later, there was no routine sharing of API data by Irish-based carriers". The hole is considered to be "small". Don't know if that was fixed since then (end of 2017).